# im trying to display what the user enter with array but i cant figure it out

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, constants, display

the output is supposed to display what the user has entered like
please enter your number: 1 2 3 4
the original array is: 1 2 3 4

what I was trying to do was use a for loop with the user info in there to display whatever was in num but it's not working and I can't think of anything else. but I keep getting this error  The original array is
3
0
0
0
when I just enter 3 0

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    const int MAX_SIZE = 100;
    int myArray [MAX_SIZE] = {};
    
    int main (){
        // user input variable using an integer
        int num =0;
        // variable to iterate over the array user input 
        int count ;
        cout<< " enter a non zero integer value ( 0 when done )"<<endl;
        cin>> num;
         myArray [0] = num;
        count+=num;
    
        while (num!=0){
            // loop to ask user info 
             cout<< "enter a non zero integer value ( 0 when done )"<< endl;
             cin>>num;
             myArray [count] = num;
             //incrementing each value that the user has enter
             count++;
        }
        // for loop to print user info 
        cout<< " The original array is "<<endl;
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            cout<< myArray[i]<<endl;
        }
    
    
        return 0;
    
        
    }
```

Comment: Why `count+=num;`? Also why don't you initialize `count` to anything?

Comment: i was trying to increment it and also what would initializing it do

Comment: Then why not `count++;`? `num` is a value that just got entered by the user and probably isn't `1`.

Comment: i did after myArray [count] = num ;

Comment: Right. Why didn't you do the same thing both times?

Comment: im confuse both time how

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the `count+=num` at the start.

When the program starts and you enter '3', at line 15, `count` has value 3. Now the program enters the loop and you input '0'. `myArray[count]` now assigns 0 at the index 3, and now the array holds values [3, 0, 0, 0], and then you add 1 to the `count` variable, making its value 4. Subsequently when you print out the array you get 3 0 0 0.

A fix for this would be at the start to simply write `count++` instead of `count+=num`

Comment: okay i have done that but it also count the 0 instead of teminating it

Comment: You'll have to rethink how you've ordered your statements, then. Because right now, you don't check whether `num` was `0` until _after_ you've stored it in `myArray` and updated `count`.

Comment: then after `cin>>num` write `if (num == 0) break;` so you break out of the loop before assigning the value to the array

Comment: ok so is it my for loop that is incorrect cause I had a for  while loop to finish the program if the user has enter 0

Comment: you just have to check if the user has entered 0 before assigning the value to the array, the for loop has nothing to do with it

Comment: okay I get that... but isn't that what my while loop is doing

Comment: yeah, but the while loop checks the condition _before_ executing the instructions inside, so you have to manually break the loop in this case

Comment: okay make sense so i have put this inside my while loop if (num == 0){
            break;   still doesn't work tho I doubt I'm doing it right

Comment: yeah that's correct

Comment: okay now its only printing from the second number to 0 like 120    20

Comment: try to go through your code and spot the mistake yourself, we cannot solve every problem for you. If you really are stuck then that's okay to ask for help, but you have to at least try. I can suggest you mentally go line by line and see what the program is doing